# How does Drupal display the correct time for a specific time zone?

Tags: datetime

I have a custom module that displays today's date and time:

```
t('Today: ') . date('d F - H:i')
```

When I change a user's time zone on their account page the time is 'magically' outputted correctly.

How does Drupal do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic comes from PHP's [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set):

> Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

Drupal uses it in

- [`drupal_session_initialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_initialize/7)
- [`drupal_session_regenerate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_regenerate/7)
- [`_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_page_cache/7)

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the code itself,  but it likely uses this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php